# IE11: <link> not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

I insert the following between the `<head>` tags:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="css/stylesheet" href="fileadmin/css/konsensusempfehlung.css">
```

This stylesheet does affect my HTML code in Firefox.
However in IE11 it does not.

konsensusempfehlung.css:

```
tr.hauptzeile {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: left;
}

tr.tr-even{
    background-color: #edf7f9;
}

th {
    padding: 0.5em;
}

td.td-0 {
    font-weight: bold;
}

td {
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.table-scrollable {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    margin: 0 0 1em;
}

.table-scrollable::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
}

.table-scrollable::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 3px solid #fff;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: If you get a message saying that your question appears to be mostly code and needs more detail… try providing more detail instead of copy/pasting the error message into the question half a dozen times.

Comment: But it's just a threshold and in this case the problem is already fully described in a few words

Comment: Look in the developer console of your browser under resources. If your stylesheet doesn't show up at all, your `link` tag is wrong. If it shows up but 404's, your `href` path is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the proper type.

`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="yourLink">`

Comment: That's what I did, problem still there.

Comment: You might also have a problem with the link.... start with a `/` for an absolute path

Comment: to test if your path is correct copy and past the `href` into your URL

Comment: That's it!! The root slash is needed by IE11! Thanks!

Comment: but you know what's really weird? I open a new tab via javascript (for printing purposes!), add everything to it (html, body, link stylesheet ecetera) and apparently I need the root slash in this case. BUT on my main page, I include stylesheets WITHOUT the root slash and there doesn't seem to be a problem.

Comment: lol agree, I hate taking it into account during web development. It's as if you work in kindergarten and there's that one child ... which secretely makes you think ... please die in a fire. Sorry. I said it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the value of the type attribute from `"css/stylesheet"` to `"text/css"`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this type

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="konsensusempfehlung.css" />
</head>
```

OR if you want to target only IE, Then try this.

```
<head>
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="konsensusempfehlung.css" />
<![endif]-->
</head>
```

Let me know further clearification

Comment: I shortened the href attribute as you said. Result: now it doesn't work in IE11 AND Firefox. So the path is correct as in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Should use `text/css` in link type. Also set href to `your link` . Shouldn't be a browser issue though

Comment: Oh sorry, I actually did set type to "text/css". I removed as suggested elsewhere but it didn't solve the issue. What do you mean by setting href to "you link"? I did set it to the correct location of the css in the TYPO3 backend?

Comment: <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="konsensusempfehlung.css">
</head>

Try by not specifying the type. Maybe it'll work (P.S. Accept the edit pls)

Comment: but I already tried removing the type attribute! and also shortening the href attribute is not the solution (see below).